# PHP: Filling Form Input non-intrusively Using DOM or REGEX

Tags: php, regex, forms, dom

I'm working on a user authentication system. Because I want it to be as customizable and flexible as possible, I do not want to mix PHP with HTML. I have developed a simple template engine which works just fine (uses pure HTML files for layout only). However I have a problem with forms.
In some cases (such as when input validation fails) I would like to make them remember the previously entered data. I use output buffering to display the end HTML to the user and so I have the whole layout stored in a string. What I'm trying to do in this string is find specific HTML elements (by their ID attributes) and subsequently change their values.
I know how to solve the problem in case text or password fields, but I'll also be using comboboxes and those need to be handled differently.
I was thinking of using DOM to achieve the task, but so far my attempts have not been successful.

So here's what I want to do:

1. find an element by its ID in the string using DOM change the element
   appropriately replace the old element with the new one in the
   string, but keep the rest of the string unchanged

Here's a simple (not working) snippet (should be enough to illustrate the problem):

```
<?php
$content = "<input id=\"id\" name=\"name\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" />";
$itemid = "id";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($content);
$item = $dom->getElementById($itemid);
if($item)
{
$value = "New Value";
$newitem = $item;
$newitem->setAttribute('value', $value);
$item = $item->saveXML();
$newitem = $newitem->saveXML();
$content = str_replace($item, $newitem, $content);
}
echo $content;
?>
```

Or should I go with REGEX instead?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with [Simple dom html parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
$data = $content = "<input id=\"id\" name=\"name\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" />";
$html = str_get_html($data);
$html->find("input[id='id']",0)->value = "New Value";
echo $html->save();
```

Cant be easier.

Comment: Hello. Great suggestion - looks like just what I was after. Best thing is that unlike DOM saving methods this script seems to leave the rest of the (X)HTML unaltered.

Comment: yes, DOMDocument saveXML produces an altered version of HTML by reading [here](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php). But i think there are better beautifiers out there.. So the real deal is to change/retrieve with ease the attributes/tags you want. I tested a lot of such tools (Simple dom html parser, phpquery, ganon) but i tend to use the first one, for speed / ease factors.

Answer (score 1):

No, to regex.  DOM is the proper choice.  However your implementation may be incorrect.  IIRC, the code should look something like this:

```
    if ($item) {
        $value = "New Value";
        $item->removeAttribute('value');
        $item->setAttribute('value', $value);
        $content = $dom->saveXML();
    }
```

Also, your code may need additional tailoring, for elements such as `<textarea>` and `<select>`.

Although this may not work with the way you're implementing your system, I'd like to suggest using jQuery.  Using PHP's [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), you can "import" PHP variables into client-side code.  Then, having imported your values, you can use jQuery's DOM and in particular, [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), which intelligently sets the human notion of "value" on form elements, so you wouldn't have to tailor the logic yourself.  If you'd like more clarification on this option, do comment, and I'm sure I or someone else will be happy to guide you in this direction.

Comment: Thank you. The code was incorrect indeed. The Jquery option you mentioned sounds interesting, but for now I'd rather keep Javascript out of it, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler version of your code:

```
<?php
$content = <<<HTML
<input id="id" name="name" type="text" value="" />
HTML;

$item_ID = "id";
$dom     = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$item = $dom->getElementById($item_ID);
$item->setAttribute("value", "New Value");
$content = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $content;
```

### Points

- If you're inputting and outputting HTML, use `saveHTML` and
  `loadHTML` methods, not the XML ones.
- `DOMDocument` already does the job of replacing for you, so you
  don't need to.
- For HTML strings, I like to use the **[heredoc syntax](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)**

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your code works, but it really does not solve my problem as I'm actually outputting XHTML. But I'll at least know when to use loadHTML.